# How can I simulate click event in Stars Rating Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to integrate the Stars Rating Widget- http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/

(I am using widget from demo 6, after 3)

after the stars are get click, the event raised with ui object

```
 callback: function (ui, type, value) {
                        var arr = ui.$stars.find("a");
   ...
```

//and the html form is:

```
                <form id="rat" action="" method="post">
                        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1" title="Poor"  />
                        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2" title="Ahh"  />
                        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3" title="Good"  />
                        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="4" title="Very Good"  />
                        <input type="radio" name="rate" value="5" title="Superb"/>

                        <input type="submit" value="Rate it!" />
                </form>
```

When the user click on the stars, it is working for me,
What I am trying to  do, is to 'fake' the click behavior, e.g inside my code, to click on the stars,

As far as I understand it, I have two options
1)To fake click (I tried it, but it generate post to me, which I don't like) 
2)To get the ui object, and call the same logic as the click event

Can you help me solve my problem?

(I need to simulate the click event, just because I want to improve the usability by
selecting the rating by the keyboard..)

Thanks.

Edit:

```
I tried combination of the following, non of them started the animation..
    //$("#rat").stars("select", 5);
    //$("#rat").click();
    //$("#rat:first").trigger("submit");
    // document.forms[0].submit();
    //jQuery('#rat').rating();
    //$('#rat').rating('select', 1);
     //$('#rat').show();
```

Edit2:
   I am able to select the stars with the following code, but not to start the animation

```
  $("#rat").stars("select", 0);
  $("#rat").show();
```

Edit3
   I did work around, but I still don't get the fancy animation

```
  function blinkStars(value) {
      $("#rat").stars("select", value);
      $("#rat").show();
      setTimeout(function () { $("#rat").stars("select", 0); $("#rat").show(); }, 600);
            }
```

Edit4 - I was asked to give more details about the ajax call, so it look like

```
           $(function () {
                $("#rat").children().not(":radio").hide();
                // Create stars
                $("#rat").stars({
                    cancelShow: false,
                    callback: function (ui, type, value) {
                        var arr = ui.$stars.find("a");

                        arr.slowEach(100,
                        function () { $(this).animate({ top: "28px" }, 300) },
                        function () {

                            $.post("/Home/Vote", { rate: value}, function (data) {

                                //do some work here..

                            }, "json");


                            $("#loader").fadeIn(function () {


                                $("#loader").fadeOut(function () {
                                    arr.slowEach(100, function () { $(this).animate({ top: 0 }, 300) });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
```

I will be more than glade to make the animation working..

Comment: The examples on that link don't even work for me, all I see are the original forms.  maybe not the best choice in widget?

Comment: I was able to make it work when user click on it, it's very cool widget.. :)

Comment: ok im giving a whole new answer

Comment: Evan thank you for trying to help, I hope you will nail it!

Comment: Can you give me more details about the ajax call it makes?

Comment: How are going to use the keyboard to select the rating? left/right arrows and/or enter key? And by animation, do you mean the hover effect from red to yellow on the stars?

Comment: The usage will be, up will select the 5 stars, down will select 1 star, the animation is all the stars going down, and then they goes up, you can see the demo 6c in the link above

Comment: @Delashmate have you got this on JSFiddle maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="rat" action="" method="post">
       <input type="radio" id="rate1" name="rate" value="1" title="Poor"  />
       <input type="radio" id="rate2" name="rate" value="2" title="Ahh"  />
       <input type="radio" id="rate3" name="rate" value="3" title="Good"  />
       <input type="radio" id="rate4" name="rate" value="4" title="Very Good"  />
       <input type="radio" id="rate5" name="rate" value="5" title="Superb"/>

       <input type="submit" value="Rate it!" />
</form> 


<script>
       $("#rate4").click(); //clicks the 'Very Good' star
</script>
```

Comment: It's look like the solution, but I tried it, and it doesn't start the animation also.. what I am missing?!

Comment: does the form need to be submitted for this?

Comment: when the user click on the stars the form submit, but if you will read the code, you will see the stars listen to event (I don't know which one, in the code it's mention as callback) and with ajax do his work..so actually there is no post at all, the form is submitted with ajax and not with regular post

Answer (score 0):

a couple things on the site link u provided:

"NOTE: With the newest jQuery (1.6) the rating control doesn't work properly, due to the changes to the attr() handling for the "disabled" attribute.
The fix will be included in new release, as soon as jQuery UI team officialy include jQuery 1.6 to download.

With that being said, you are now able to download a <> shared by Colin Guthrie, thanks! :)
Optionally, you can download a <> right away. "

so if you are using after 1.6 you need to make sure to have the patch and use this:

```
$('input[name="rate"][value="3"]').prop("checked",true);

$('#rat input[type="submit"]').click();
```

if you are using before 1.6 use

```
$('input[name="rate"][value="3"]').attr("checked",true);

$('#rat input[type="submit"]').click();
```

Comment: I tired your answer, but it is made refresh to my site, thing I would like to avoid, and also doesn't show the animation

Comment: I tried both, just to be sure, but it still refresh my page.. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

a few more options to trigger the event you would like:

`.change()` ;
`.trigger()` ;
`.trigger('click')` ;
`.trigger('change')` ;
`$('#rat').get(0).selectedIndex = 2` ;

unfortunatelly i wont be able to test until monday.
all yours :)

Comment: I just tried all of your options, non of them worked to me, but I didn't try to dig on them, so maybe you are near to the solution